# Overview / Tutorial on moving from dl.util.concurrent to java.util.concurrent

Tags: java, concurrency

We have been using Doug Lea's concurrent library for more than 8 years now. For backwards compatibility reasons our code was restricted to use Java 2 language level and JDK 1.3 library.

Now we are working on a major new release and are finally able to use Java 5 features.

We think we should **move from** using the "old" concurrency library **to** the util.concurrent features from JSR 166.

The difficulty we face is the **transition between those two libraries**. Both have similar concepts, but classes are named differently, features *seem* to be missing...

Are there any specific resources on this? Articles, tutorials, overviews on the **commonalities and differences***...

I searched the web of course but came up empty.

Yes, I know that what I should really do is re-read *Concurrent Programming in Java* and finally read *Java Concurrency* and then - with the full knowledge - write the transition guide myself, tailored for our project...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered contacting Doug Lea directly?

His contact information is listed on http://g.oswego.edu/ where there is also an overview of his work on the concurrent utilities but as far as I can see, not what you ask for here.

Comment: Actually - no, haven't thought about it. In a way obvious. Maybe I'm too shy ;-) Let's see if anything turns up and if not, I will do that, thanks.

Comment: If this is important to your business, then consider hiring him as a consultant.  Academics usually like being paid for what they would do anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you could not find any resources on the web for this problem.

Just as an example:

- [A high-level overview by Sun](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/concurrency/)
- [A short tutorial covering the basics](http://www.cs.drexel.edu/~shartley/ConcProgJava/)

Like you said - there are many a fine books on this subject, and each one will get you where you need. Get [one of those](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201310090), read it beginning to end, and that's all you need to know.

Comment: I'm sorry you misunderstood. I stated explicitly that I am looking for resources on **comparisons** of those two libraries. Ideal case: "You have been using `FutureResult` now use `Xyz`.

Comment: @Gerd - I believe that if you learn the subject in depth, you will have no problem making those comparisons yourself. In any case, I do not know of any specific material on moving from said library to `java.util.concurrent`

Comment: @Yuval - I know and respect that you're trying to help. That's why I wrote "Yes, I know that what I should...". But this is a matter of time and work-load right now. I will do that eventually - bought Java Concurrency by Brian Goetz already. But still I need to decide in the nearest future whether to continue using the old library or moving, and if we move, how to do this. Also, this does not affect me alone but a 6-7 person team.